# Adding a table header on this code?

Tags: json, header

I would like to add headers per below but I unable to do so.  I searched everywhere but still nothing.  I'm still very new to this but any help would be appreciated.  Can you assist?

```
function myFunction(response) {
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
var i;
var out = "<table>";

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += "<tr><td>" + 
    arr[i].id +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].bkname +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].pbname +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].year +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].type +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].con +
    "</td></tr>";
}
out += "</table>"
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
```

}

Comment: Add the header row before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the header in the initial value of `out`

```
var out = "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>BKName</th><th>PBName</th><th>Year</th><Type</th><th>Con</th></tr>";
```